# Integrating Events into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the process of developing a website for a not-for-profit organization, and I thought that Wordpress would be a great tool to use as the base CMS for the site. Building the site into Wordpress has not been a problem, but I have been having a difficult time finding a plugin to use to help them organize and advertise upcoming Events. Currently, they use Google Calendar, but are trying to move to something that integrates more cleanly into their site.

Essentially, I need a Wordpress events/calendar plugin with these features:
 + Add reoccurring events with start and end time
 + Each event should have its own page (reoccurring events should be shown as a single page)
 + Display all events in a mini-calendar and a full calendar/list view

It would also be nice to have these features:
 * Ability to categorize/tag events
 * Ability to add a picture to go with the event

I'm indifferent on these features:
 - Being able to RSVP
 - Paying for events
 - Import/Export calendars

There are many Events/Calendar plugins out there for Wordpress, but I can't seem to decide which one is worth me spending time to use for this website. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Category called "Events" and design a layout for that cat. in particular.
then post new events to that category.

also, have you looked in to this plugins?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-events/screenshots/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager/screenshots/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager-extended/screenshots/

Comment: Have you used either of these plugins? Do you recommend one over the other?

Comment: Well, it depends on your needs, I have used the Wp-events.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem :) http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late for you, but others may find it helpful. This plug-in fits the bill for the features you were after:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/

*(Full disclosure: I wrote this plug-in)*.